# How to turn off Parameter Hints on parameter name in PhpStorm 2017?

Tags: phpstorm, code-hinting

How to turn off Parameter Hints on parameter name in PhpStorm 2017?

https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/03/new-in-phpstorm-2017-1-parameter-hints/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

navigate to Editor | General | Appearance and deselect Show parameter name hints.

(It's  in the link you provided.)